# Handling Complex Dependencies Between Object Properties (Auto Update Dependent Properties)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, oop, design-patterns, dependencies

I have a tree structure of objects, and their properties have very complicated dependencies on surrounding objects determined by where they are in the tree.  I have hard coded a lot of these dependencies, and tried to create some sort of update loop (where if a property gets updated, based on the design, all of the properties that depend on it get updated, and in the correct order), but I want to handle it in a more generic/abstract way, instead of hard coding a bunch of update calls to different objects.

Let's say, for example, I have 1 superclass, and 3 subclasses, and then a separate container object.

**Shape**
properties: parentContainer, index, left, top, width, height
methods: updateLeft(), updateTop(), updateWidth(), updateHeight()

**Square inherits from Shape

Triangle inherits from Shape

Circle inherits from Shape**

**ShapeContainer**
properties: shapes
methods: addShape(shape, index), removeShape(index)

I'll give a pseudocode example update method to illustrate how these dependencies crop up:

```
Square.updateTop() {
    var prevShape = null;
    if (this.index != 0) {
        prevShape = this.parentContainer.shapes[this.index - 1];
    }
    var nextSquareInContainer = null;
    for (var i = this.index; i < this.parentContainer.shapes.length; i++) {
        var shape = this.parentContainer.shapes[i];
        if(shape instanceof Square) {
            nextSquareInContainer = shape;
            break;
        }
    }
    var top = 0;
    if (prevShape != null && nextSquareInContainer != null) {
        top = prevShape.top + nextSquareInContainer.width;
    } else {
        top = 22;
    }
    this.top = top;
}
```

So, any square objects added to the shapeConatiner will depend on the previous shape's top value and the next square found in the container's width value for its top value.

Here is some code to set up an example shape container:

```
var shapeContainer = new ShapeContainer();
var triangle = new Triangle();
var circle = new Circle();
var square1 = new Square();
var square2 = new Square();
shapeContainer.addShape(triangle, 0);
shapeContainer.addShape(circle, 1);
shapeContainer.addShape(square1, 2);
shapeContainer.addShape(square2, 3);
```

So, I guess the crux of the issue is, if I update the above circle's top value, I want the top value of square1 to be automatically updated (because there is a one way dependency between square1's top value, and circle's top value).  So one way I can do this (the way I've been doing it, in combination with some other specific knowledge of my problem domain to simplify the calls), is to add the code similar to the following to Circle's updateTop method (really it would have to be added to each shape's updateTop method):

```
Circle.updateTop() {
    // Code to actually calculate and update Circle's top value, note this
    // may depend on its own set of dependencies
    var nextShape = this.parentContainer.shapes[this.index + 1];
    if (nextShape instanceof Square) {
        nextShape.updateTop();
    }
}
```

This type of design is fine for a few simple dependencies between objects, but my project has dozens of types of objects with probably hundreds of dependencies between their properties.  I've coded it this way, but it is very difficult to reason about when trying to add new features, or troubleshoot a bug.

Is there some sort of design pattern out there to set up dependencies between object properties, and then when one property is updated,  it updates all of the properties on other objects that depend on it (which may then trigger further updating of properties that depend on the now newly updated properties)? Some sort of declarative syntax for specifying these dependencies would probably be best for readability/maintainability.

Another issue is, a property may have several dependencies, that ALL must be updated before I want that property to update itself.

I've been looking into a pub/sub type of solution, but I thought this was a complicated enough problem to reach out for help.  As a side note, I'm working in javascript.

Comment: It sounds like what you need is data-binding. Check out [Addy Osmani's talk on Object.observe()](http://addyosmani.com/blog/the-future-of-data-binding-is-object-observe/) where you can also find several polyfills that might be an answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the hackish solution I came up with. I create a wrapper class, that you pass in anonymous functions for getter/setter/updaters.  Then you make a call of prop1.dependsOn(prop2) to declaratively set up dependencies.  It involves setting up a directed acyclic graph of the dependencies between object properties, and then when a property value is updated, explicitly making a call to resolve the related dependencies using a topological sort. I didn't put much thought into efficiency, and I bet somebody could come up with a much more robust/performant solution, but I think this will do for now. Sorry for the code dump, but I thought it could be of some help to somebody trying to solve a similar problem down the road. If somebody wants to make this syntactically cleaner, be my guest.

```
// This is a class that will act as a wrapper for all properties 
// that we want to tie to our dependency graph.
function Property(initialValue, ctx) {
    // Each property will get a unique id.
    this.id = (++Property.id).toString();
    this.value = initialValue;
    this.isUpdated = false;
    this.context = ctx;
    Property.dependsOn[this.id] = [];
    Property.isDependedOnBy[this.id] = [];
    Property.idMapping[this.id] = this;
}
// Static properties on Property function.
Property.id = 0;
Property.dependsOn = {};
Property.isDependedOnBy = {};
Property.idMapping = {};

// Calling this updates all dependencies from the node outward.
Property.resolveDependencies = function (node) {
    node = node.id;
    var visible = [];
    // Using Depth First Search to mark visibility (only want to update dependencies that are visible).
    var depthFirst = function (node) {
        visible.push(node);
        for (var i = 0; i < Property.isDependedOnBy[node].length; i++) {
            depthFirst(Property.isDependedOnBy[node][i]);
        }
    };
    depthFirst(node);
    // Topological sort to make sure updates are done in the correct order.
    var generateOrder = function (inbound) {
        var noIncomingEdges = [];
        for (var key in inbound) {
            if (inbound.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (inbound[key].length === 0) {
                    // Only call update if visible.
                    if (_.indexOf(visible, key) !== -1) {
                        Property.idMapping[key].computeValue();
                    }
                    noIncomingEdges.push(key);
                    delete inbound[key];
                }
            }
        }

        for (var key in inbound) {
            if (inbound.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                for (var i = 0; i < noIncomingEdges.length; i++) {
                    inbound[key] = _.without(inbound[key], noIncomingEdges[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        // Check if the object has anymore nodes.
        for (var prop in inbound) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(inbound, prop)) {
                generateOrder(inbound);
            }
        }

    };
    generateOrder(_.clone(Property.dependsOn));
};
Property.prototype.get = function () {
    return this.value;
}
Property.prototype.set = function (value) {
    this.value = value;
}
Property.prototype.computeValue = function () {
    // Call code that updates this.value.
};
Property.prototype.dependsOn = function (prop) {
    Property.dependsOn[this.id].push(prop.id);
    Property.isDependedOnBy[prop.id].push(this.id);
}

function PropertyFactory(methodObject) {
    var self = this;
    var PropType = function (initialValue) {
        Property.call(this, initialValue, self);
    }
    PropType.prototype = Object.create(Property.prototype);
    PropType.prototype.constructor = PropType;
    if (methodObject.get !== null) {
        PropType.prototype.get = methodObject.get;
    }
    if (methodObject.set !== null) {
        PropType.prototype.set = methodObject.set;
    }
    if (methodObject.computeValue !== null) {
        PropType.prototype.computeValue = methodObject.computeValue;
    }

    return new PropType(methodObject.initialValue);
}
```

And here is an example of what setting up a property looks like:

```
function MyClassContainer() {
    this.children = [];
    this.prop = PropertyFactory.call(this, {
        initialValue: 0,
        get: null,
        set: null,
        computeValue: function () {
            var self = this.context;
            var updatedVal = self.children[0].prop.get() + self.children[1].prop.get();
            this.set(updatedVal);
        }
    });
}
MyClassContainer.prototype.addChildren = function (child) {
    if (this.children.length === 0 || this.children.length === 1) {
        // Here is the key line.  This line is setting up the dependency between
        // object properties.
        this.prop.dependsOn(child.prop);
    }
    this.children.push(child);
}

function MyClass() {
    this.prop = PropertyFactory.call(this, {
        initialValue: 5,
        get: null,
        set: null,
        computeValue: null
    });
}

var c = new MyClassContainer();
var c1 = new MyClass();
var c2 = new MyClass();
c.addChildren(c1);
c.addChildren(c2);
```

And here is an example of actually updating a property once all of this infrastructure is set up:

```
c1.prop.set(3);
Property.resolveDependencies(c1.prop);
```

I feel like this is a pretty powerful pattern for programs that require really complicated dependencies.  Knockout JS has something similar, with computedObservables (and they use a wrapper in a similar fashion), but you can only tie the computed property to other properties on the same object from what I can tell.  The above pattern allows you to arbitrarily associate object properties as dependencies.